# How can I use dynamic value names in sessionStorage?

Tags: javascript, json, session-storage

I have a JSON object that has a bunch of data about witnesses to an accident. It looks like this:

```
{
  'name0': John Doe,
  'name1': Jane Doe
}
```

I would like to access them using a loop and apply them to my sessionStorage like this:

```
sessionStorage.setItem(`w${count}Name`, `data.name${count}`);
```

I can't seem to get this to work....

Comment: hey there, you want have an item per property of your JSON object?

Comment: Why won't you store the whole JSON? `sessionStorage.setItem('witnesses', JSON.stringify(jsonObject))` ?

Comment: `sessionStorage.setItem('w${count}Name', data['name${count}']);`

Comment: maybe consider doing what DontVoteMeDown is suggesting. Maybe even encode the json before populating the session storage item.

Comment: @Brandon - PERFECT! This works EXACTLY how I wanted. You are a ROCK STAR!